# Android Studio proxy setting is set on no proxy, But still proxy is enabled

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, proxy

On My Gradle sync, I recive this error :

```
 Received status code 501 from server: Tor is not an HTTP Proxy
```

and my proxy setting is set on no proxy !

The Best

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem. If I could not fix it I will format my laptop.

Comment: My Problem solved, remove proxy setting from your ~/.gradle/gradle.properties

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem. Removing proxy settings in global gradle properties file fixed my problem. Check here; `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`. The folder in macOS and windows is hidden. You can also find the related question and answer here; [Disabling proxy settings in Android Studio 3.2.1 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53546619/1367450)

Comment: thank you. i had this problem on Ubuntu and you saved me

Comment: The path for windows is: `C:\Users\<Your-User>\.gradle\gradle.properties`

Comment: This Saved My Day.Thanks