# Disabling proxy settings in Android Studio 3.2.1 not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, proxy

Sometimes I am working in internal network and have to setup `proxy settings` in `Android Studio` now I have changed the network and need to disable `proxy settings` to be able to download dependencies.

But somehow I can't disable proxy configuration. Android Studio is still trying to connect through proxy. Here is what I did to disable it;

1. Removed `http` and `https` configuration in `gradle.properties / local.properties`.
2. Disabled proxy configuration in `Preferences-> System Settings-> HTTP Proxy`.
3. Removed operating system proxy settings in network.
4. Uninstall & install Java
5. Uninstall & install SDK
6. Uninstall & install Android Studio

Unfortunately none of above steps and the answers in community worked. Feeling so desperate :)

Here is the screenshot of Android Studio. My final choice will be formatting macOS.

[image]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think you have global properties for proxy settings.
You can check the global gradle properties from here.

> We can define a `gradle.properties` file and set the property in this
>   file. We can place the file in our project directory or in the 
>   `<USER_HOME>/.gradle` directory. The properties defined in the property
>   file in our home directory take precedence over the properties defined
>   in the file in our project directory. As a bonus we can also define
>   system properties in a gradle.properties file, we only have to prefix
>   the property name with systemProp..

[Global gradle proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523804/global-gradle-proxy-settings)

Comment: Thanks Canpolat. .gradle folder was hidden in macOS. It was cached in that file.

Comment: Even worse in my case it was not even at the end or start at the file, the lines were spread across randomly... I had actually looked here before and missed it ='D

Comment: I had the exact same issue and was able to fix it by deleting the proxy lines from root/.grade/gradle.properties 

Why isn't this "global" file affected by toggling proxy on and off in Android Studio? I don't remember adding this myself but I may have and forgotten about it...

Comment: @Flyview seems like a bug