# stuck on Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml in android studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

After adding volley dependency and press sync. I canceled syncing the dependency and after that when I reopen the project I get this stuck to build the project. I also click on clean the project and invalid cache and restart buttons. but It can not be changed.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

I had enabled https proxy, through the Android Studio settings dialog.
And when I needed to use it on another network, I was not able to disable it through the same settings dialog.

So, I removed the proxy configuration lines directly in the Global Gradle Properties file (<USER_HOME>\.gradle\gradle.properties) and my problem was solved.

```
gradle.properties
...
# systemProp.http.proxyHost=
# systemProp.http.proxyPort=80
# systemProp.https.proxyHost=
# systemProp.https.proxyPort=80
```

[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598781/6831019)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by deleting the `<USER_HOME>\.gradle` folder and restart AndroidStudio

Comment: It is better to rename the gradle caches dir prior to remove it. The source of this issue could be that maven repository is down for some reason and gradle can not fetch its maven-metadata.xml. Remove all caches is too hurry decision.

Answer (score 0):

change your network and run again !!

Comment: what does it mean change network? I have only one wifi.