# How to fix freezing sync - Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml

Tags: android, maven, kotlin

I am trying open project in Android Studio 4.0.1 and after I import it, Gradle sync starts, but it always ends in state "Gradle: Download maven-metadata.xml".
I have tried several solutions that I've seen on [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63075551/stuck-on-gradle-download-maven-metadata-xml-in-android-studio)

Is there any workaround for this?