# Download Maven-metadata.xml is taking more than 30 minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]My other projects are working fine as expected, but my one project is stuck on downloading maven-metadata . After restoring the android studio default settings I am facing this issue. Is there any possible reason for this. I tried various solution in the SF but none are helping.
I am using Android studio 4.1

**Project level**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    ext.serialization_version = '1.0-M1-1.4.0-rc'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        // Add the Esri public Bintray Maven repository
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
        maven { url 'https://esri.jfrog.io/artifactory/arcgis' }
      
    }
}

ext {
    // Sdk and tools
    minSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.2'

    // App dependencies
    daggerVersion = '2.30.1'
    retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
    lifeCycleVersion = '2.2.0'
    roomVersion = "2.2.5"
    mlKitVersion = "24.0.3"

    //Test dependencies
    junitVersion = '4.13.1'
    mockitoVersion = '3.6.28'
    powerMockito = '1.6.2'
    espressoVersion = '3.3.0'

    leakCanaryVersion = '2.5'
    googleMapVersion = '17.1.0'
    permissionVersion = '4.1.0'

    esriMapVersion = '100.10.0'
    workManagerVersion = '2.3.3'
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.30'
}

ext.libraries = [
        appCompact                : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0",
        constraintLayout          : "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4",
        materialComponents        : "com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha04",
        recyclerView              : "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-beta01",

        mlKit                     : "com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:$mlKitVersion",

        lifeCycleRuntime          : "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifeCycleVersion",
        lifeCycleRuntimeExtensions: "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifeCycleVersion",
        lifeCycleCompiler         : "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifeCycleVersion",

        firebaseCloudMessaging    : "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.0",
        firebseAnalytic           : "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0",
        firebaseCrashlytics       : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0",
        firebasePerf              : "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.10",

        roomRuntime               : "androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion",
        roomCompiler              : "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion",
        roomRxJava2               : "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$roomVersion",

        rxJava                    : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.20",
        rxAndroid                 : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1",
        rxKotlin                  : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.4.0",

        okhttpLogging             : "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0",
        retrofitConverter         : "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion",
        retrofit                  : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion",
        retrofitRxJava2Adapter    : "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion",

        dagger                    : "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion",
        daggerAndroid             : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion",
        daggerAndroidSupport      : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion",
        daggerCompiler            : "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion",
        daggerAndroidProcessor    : "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion",

        multidex                  : 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1',
        kotlinStdLib              : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version",

        //Libraries for Tests
        junit                     : "junit:junit:$junitVersion",
        expressoCore              : "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espressoVersion",
        mockito                   : "org.mockito:mockito-core:$mockitoVersion",
        mockitoKotlin             : "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0",

        //Libraries for development
        leakCanary                : "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$leakCanaryVersion",
        leakCanaryNoop            : "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.3",

        //Library for Font
        FontSupportLibrary        : "com.android.support:support-compat:$buildToolsVersion",

        //Library for Google maps
        googleMapLocation         : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$googleMapVersion",

        //Permission(PermissionsDispatcher)
        permission                : "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:$permissionVersion",
        permissionProcessor       : "com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:$permissionVersion",

        //Library for ESRI maps
        esriMap                   : "com.esri.arcgisruntime:arcgis-android:$esriMapVersion",

        //Image loading
        imageLoader               : "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0",
        imageLoaderCompiler       : "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0",

        //Logging
        kotlinLogger              : "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:2.0.3",
        slf4jAPI                  : "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion",
        slf4jAPINOP               : "org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:$slf4jVersion",
        logbackAndroid            : "com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0",

        //Tools
        tooLargeTool              : 'com.gu.android:toolargetool:0.2.1@aar',

        //Work-Manager
        workManager               : "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:$workManagerVersion",

        //Shimmer
        shimmer                   : "com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0",

        //Biometric
        biometric                 : "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.1"
]

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**appLevel**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version '2.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    ext {
        APP_NAME = "@string/app_name"
        APP_NAME_DEV = "@string/app_name_dev"
        APP_NAME_AUTOMATION = "@string/app_name_automation"
    }
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode project.hasProperty("versionCode") ? project.versionCode.toInteger() : 1
        versionName project.hasProperty("versionName") ? project.versionName : "2021.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

     
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath = true
            }
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('xyz')
            storePassword 'treadstone'
            keyPassword 'treadstone'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            zipAlignEnabled false
        }
        dev {
////**        Uncomment to test obfuscated dev release buildd
//            minifyEnabled true
//            shrinkResources true
//            zipAlignEnabled true
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: APP_NAME_DEV]
            buildConfigField 'int', 'locationAccuracy', '20'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'sqliteEncryptionEnabled', 'false'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        automation {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".automation"
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: APP_NAME_AUTOMATION]
            buildConfigField 'int', 'locationAccuracy', '20'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'sqliteEncryptionEnabled', 'false'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
        release {//TODO: Rename to 'prod'
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            zipAlignEnabled true
            manifestPlaceholders = [applicationLabel: APP_NAME]
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'int', 'locationAccuracy', '50'
            buildConfigField 'Boolean', 'sqliteEncryptionEnabled', 'true'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ndk {
                abiFilters 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        crewforce {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".crewforce"
            buildConfigField "String", "APPLICATION_TYPE", '"{cd521b8f-c655-42f0-b7f6-8da8423fa166}"'
            buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_ROLE", '"Firefighter"'
            buildConfigField "String", "GeoId", '"2"'
        }
        shieldforce {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".shieldforce"
            buildConfigField "String", "APPLICATION_TYPE", '"{b8850ba1-a012-41d1-b700-55ca4e47fe2b}"'
            buildConfigField "String", "DEFAULT_ROLE", '"Patrol Officer"'
            buildConfigField "String", "GeoId", '"1"'
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode
            def variantName = variant.name // CrewForceRelease or ShieldForceRelease

            outputFileName = variantName + '_' + versionName + '_' + versionCode + '.apk'
        }
    }
    variantFilter { variant ->
        def exclude = variant.name in [
                'crewforceDebug',
                'shieldforceDebug'
        ]
        variant.setIgnore(exclude)
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com" }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/guardian/android' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Android SDK libraries & Kotlin
    implementation libraries.constraintLayout
    implementation libraries.appCompact
    implementation libraries.materialComponents
    implementation libraries.recyclerView
    implementation libraries.kotlinStdLib
    //Firebase
    implementation libraries.mlKit
    implementation libraries.firebaseCloudMessaging
    implementation libraries.firebseAnalytic
    implementation libraries.firebaseCrashlytics
    implementation libraries.firebasePerf
    //Lifecycle Components
    implementation libraries.lifeCycleRuntime
    implementation libraries.lifeCycleRuntimeExtensions
    kapt libraries.lifeCycleCompiler
    //Room Database
    implementation libraries.roomRuntime
    kapt libraries.roomCompiler
    implementation libraries.roomRxJava2
    //Retrofit
    implementation libraries.okhttpLogging
    implementation libraries.retrofitConverter
    implementation libraries.retrofit
    implementation libraries.retrofitRxJava2Adapter
    //Dagger
    implementation libraries.dagger
    implementation libraries.daggerAndroid
    implementation libraries.daggerAndroidSupport
    kapt libraries.daggerCompiler
    kapt libraries.daggerAndroidProcessor
    //RxJava
    implementation libraries.rxJava
    implementation libraries.rxAndroid
    implementation libraries.rxKotlin
    implementation libraries.multidex
    //Test
    testImplementation libraries.mockito
    testImplementation libraries.junit
    testImplementation(libraries.mockitoKotlin) {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib'
    }
    androidTestImplementation libraries.expressoCore
    //Development
    debugImplementation libraries.leakCanary
    releaseImplementation libraries.leakCanaryNoop
    devImplementation libraries.leakCanary
    automationImplementation libraries.leakCanaryNoop
    //Downloadable Font
    implementation libraries.FontSupportLibrary
    //Google Map
    implementation libraries.googleMapLocation
    //RuntimePermission(PermissionsDispatcher)
    implementation libraries.permission
    kapt libraries.permissionProcessor
    // ESRI Map
    implementation libraries.esriMap
    //Turf Routing
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.4.1'
    //JTS Routing
    implementation 'org.locationtech.jts:jts-core:1.17.1'
    //Work Manager
    implementation libraries.workManager
    //SQLCipher
    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.4.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.commonsware.cwac:saferoom.x:1.0.0'
    //Logging
    implementation libraries.kotlinLogger
    implementation libraries.slf4jAPI
    testImplementation libraries.slf4jAPINOP
    implementation libraries.logbackAndroid
    //Image Loader
    implementation libraries.imageLoader
    kapt libraries.imageLoaderCompiler
    implementation libraries.tooLargeTool
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.2-native-mt'
    implementation 'org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:1.1'
    implementation('com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.14') {
        exclude group: 'xmlpull', module: 'xmlpull'
    }
    implementation project(':dl-parser')
    //Shimmer
    implementation libraries.shimmer
    //Biometric
    implementation libraries.biometric

    play {
        track = "internal"
        serviceAccountCredentials = file("api-7648918347200791448-85734-0a7e30fc1319.json")
        resolutionStrategy = "auto"
        outputProcessor {
            versionNameOverride = "$versionNameOverride.$versionCode"
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you add build.gradle files too project and module level it looks like there is some dependency it is having trouble downloading.

Comment: Hi Sandeep..Hope this answer solves the issue you are facing https://stackoverflow.com/a/64445751/6826629

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh I have added , can you please take a look

Comment: @ShreyasSanil I tried and my other projects are running with same configurations

Comment: @sandeepdhami your configurations look fine maybe it is caused by some cache problem. Clean cache for both android studio and gradle then let it sync for some time it would take some time initially but then it would work faster next time

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh Gradle sync is going on for 1hr 23 m & I cleared my android studio as well as cloned my project again multiple times but not luck

Comment: Have you cleared the local gradle cache?? You can check this link to know how to clear cache
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834111/gradle-store-on-local-file-system
Gradle sync should not take more than 30 mins

Comment: Yes I cleared the gradle cache

Comment: did you manage to find the problem?

Comment: No, but after I did reset my laptop, it was working fine,